# Problems redirecting Angular 15 project and .htaccess redirect on refresh

Tags: angular, .htaccess, routes, refresh

I am creating an application with Angular 15.
What I need is a redirection to the main page on refresh.

For example the user is on **app.xyz.com/summary** or **app.xyz.com/auth/login** or any other site. Then a refresh needs to redirect to **app.xyz.com**.

On my server I have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

The problem is that on refreshing I always either get loop with an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I get a 404 error on refresh because the URL is not redirected.

Part of the problem may be that **app.xyz.com** is always redirected to **app.xyz.com/auth/login** , maybe that causes a loop.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'auth/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

I am trying for hours now and am not really into the regular expressions from hat access.
Maybe someone has a hint for me to solve this.

Comment: Try building Angular app with context, say "web". And, configure the server to redirect to that context.